# REGEX expression for finding ship to address of different countries

Tags: python-re

I am trying to extract the shipping address from a commercial invoice.

One commercial invoice has ship to destination as Singapore.
The other invoice has ship to destination as Hong Kong

How do I write a regex to extract the destination address, which ends either with Singapore or Hong Kong ?

I wrote a regex to extract the shipping address from a Commercial Invoice. see below:

```
shipto = re.findall("Shipped To/FRT Forwarder\n[a-zA-Z0-9\s\#\-\,]*SINGAPORE", text).
```

My problem is the shipping address could be SINGAPORE or HONG KONG or another location. How can I make the regex more generic?

for example:
my shipping address could be
XXXX Singapore

or

YYYY Hong Kong

How do I implement a "either OR" logic in REGEX in the address extraction ?

Comment: You need to write down some sample addresses (after changing them, so they're not real addresses, but are still formatted the same way). It's going to be different depending on the kind of data you're getting. Is it coming in from a database table, a csv file, an email, a pdf? Is it the result of OCR? Is it mixed with other data? Is the address already broken up into multiple fields? What regex have you tried thus far?

Comment: I wrote a regex to  extract the shipping address from a Commercial Invoice.  see below: shipto = re.findall("Shipped To/FRT Forwarader\n[a-zA-Z0-9\s\#\-\,]*SINGAPORE", text).  My problem is the shipping address could be SINGAPORE or HONG KONG or another location.    How can I make the regex more generic?

Comment: [Edit] your original question with the comment you added. It will bring it back up to the top of Stackoverflow so more people notice the new version. By the way, there is a typo in "Forwarader". It should be "Forwarder"

Comment: You still should provide sample addresses (as text) and add them to your post, so that the problem you're trying to solve is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](https://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/regex_3.html#SEC16) helpful.

Here is how you would search for "HONG KONG" or "SINGAPORE".

```
shipto = re.findall("Shipped To/FRT Forwarder\n[a-zA-Z0-9\s\#\-\,]*(SINGAPORE|HONG KONG)", text)
```

If you want to generalize, you can do something like this:

```
shipto_regular_expression_template = "Shipped To/FRT Forwarder\n[a-zA-Z0-9\s\#\-\,]*(LOCATIONS)"

# You could get your list of locations from anywhere.
# These locations will be treated as regular expressions. themselves
list_of_locations = ["SINGAPORE", "HONG KONG", "ELSEWHERE"]

list_of_locations_joined = "|".join(list_of_locations)
shipto_regular_expression = shipto_regular_expression_template.replace("LOCATIONS", list_of_locations_joined)

re.findall(shipto_regular_expression_template, text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried the expression   shipto = re.findall("Shipped To/FRT Forwarder\n[a-zA-Z0-9\s\#\-\,]*(SINGAPORE|HONG KONG)", text).   The full shipping address for Singapore ending with SINGAPORE shows up but if the invoice is from Hong Kong,  it does not show  the full hong kong address.  What I get is just "HONG KONG"